# Issue adding another parameter to connection

Tags: sql, excel, parameters, parameter-passing

I have several connections within a workbook which I've amended to reflect an addition parameter.Originally the queries solely brought through data based upon a plant code where as now they use either plant name or plant code.

Whilst trying to amend my 3rd connection, after specifying the new parameter in the Enter Parameter Value input box, I receive an error as follows

"Bad Parameter type. Microsoft Excel is expecting a different kind of value than what was provided".

Yet with the previous connections, the specified cell was accepted and the data updated when the query was refreshed. Please can someone assist?

Comment: There is something wrong with the third connection.

Comment: Hi, I have tested using the code in SQL and the query runs.